# Cometd : Allowing multiple sessions per browser not working

Tags: java, spring, push, comet, cometd

I have a Cometd based PUSH mechanism already working on a Spring-MVC application. Currently, whenever a new tab is opened and the user tries to chat with the new tab, the connection on first tab is lost as multiple sessions per browser is set to false. For that, I tried to change the settings, and added it in web.xml, but it is not working. Any ideas?

web.xml :

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>cometd</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.cometd.server.CometDServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>maxSessionsPerBrowser</param-name>
            <param-value>-1</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>allowMultiSessionsNoBrowser</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>

    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>cometd</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/cometd/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter</filter-class>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/cometd/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

This is not helping, first tab still looses connection. What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

*Edit*

Code called when new window or tab loaded :

```
(function($)
                {

                    $(document).ready(function()
                    {

                        var cometURL = location.protocol + "//" + location.host + config.contextPath + "/cometd";
                        var connectionIntervall = null;
                        var onlineElement = document.getElementById("browser-online");
                        cometd.configure({
                            url: cometURL,
                            logLevel: 'debug'
                        });

                        cometd.addListener('/meta/handshake', _metaHandshake);
                        cometd.addListener('/meta/connect', _metaConnect);

                        cometd.handshake();

                        function _connectionEstablished()
                        {
                            clearInterval(connectionIntervall);
                            onlineElement.className="";
                        }

                        function _connectionBroken()
                        {
                            connectionIntervall = setInterval(function(){
                                onlineElement.className="offline";
                            }, 1333);

                        }

                        function _connectionClosed()
                        {
                            //$('.content-container').prepend('<div>CometD Connection Closed</div>');
                        }

                        // Function that manages the connection status with the Bayeux server
                        var _connected = false;
                        function _metaConnect(message)
                        {
                            if (cometd.isDisconnected())
                            {
                                _connected = false;
                                _connectionClosed();
                                return;
                            }

                            var wasConnected = _connected;
                            _connected = message.successful === true;
                            if (!wasConnected && _connected)
                            {
                                _connectionEstablished();
                            }
                            else if (wasConnected && !_connected)
                            {
                                _connectionBroken();
                            }
                        }

                        // Function invoked when first contacting the server and
                        // when the server has lost the state of this client
                        function _metaHandshake(handshake)
                        {
                            if (handshake.successful === true)
                            {
                                cometd.batch(function()
                                {
                                    cometDModel.subscribeToCometD();
                                    chatView.createSoul("");
                                });
                            } 
                        }
                        // Disconnect when the page unloads
                        $(window).unload(function()
                        {
                            cometd.disconnect(true);
                        });

                    });
                })(jQuery);
    }
```

Comment: With the default CometD configuration, when you open a second tab the connection with the first is *not* lost. You have to detail much better what you mean by lost, and provide evidence that it is actually lost. Configuring `maxSessionPerBrowser` to -1 is not a good idea for the reasons explained in the [documentation](https://docs.cometd.org/current/reference/#_java_server_configuration).

Comment: @sbordet : The only message thrown in Firebug is `uncaught exception: Illegal state: already disconnected`. Why is it a bad idea exactly? It is actually mentioned in the documentation that you can make it to -1, why is it bad then? In the first tab, all cometd functionality terminated and only that error is received.

Comment: It is not the only message from Firebug. You want to enable DEBUG logging for CometD and report the logs, otherwise there is no way to help you. `Illegal state: already disconnected` is thrown when your application explicitly disconnect and _then_ you call other methods, so likely an application mistake.

Comment: @sbordet : Here is the debug log which you wanted and I get when I put org.cometd in debug, open a new tab, and this is what I get : http://pastebin.com/SUgkF8G0   . I hope this proves useful so Cometd can work in multiple tabs in a single browser rather than disconnecting previous connections. Thank you.

Comment: You reported the server log. We were talking about Firebug and the client logs, where the exception was thrown. The server logs show a duplicate connect, which means that you either call `cometd.handshake()` twice from the same tab, or you have some other problem. Use Jetty not Tomcat on the server.

Comment: @sbordet I already mentioned that we only get Illegal State in firebug, NOTHING ELSE. You told me to enable debug logging, and now you want firebug log. If handshake is not called in 2nd tab, 2nd tab doesn't have cometd connection. So, the choice is, call handshake and lose connection in first tab or dont call handshake and get no connection in 2nd tab, quite a choice. I think if Cometd is not supported on Tomcat, then it should be clearly mentioned that way.

Comment: @sbordet : You wanted firebug logs, as I told you there are no firebug logs other than already disconnected. Check yourself : http://s32.postimg.org/an4ck2hc5/Screenshot_from_2016_05_19_11_17_38.png   . This error happens after a new tab is opened and cometd just tries to reconnect.

Comment: It is not true that you only get the Illegal State in firebug and NOTHING ELSE. The image you just attached shows a number of log lines of what happens in the CometD library client. Those lines shows a message with `id="51"` on the `/meta/disconnect` channel, which means that your application explicitly called disconnect. This is not CometD's fault, it's your application calling `disconnect()`. As I said multiple times, CometD perfectly supports multiple tabs, and it *is* supported in Tomcat.

Comment: I mentioned Jetty just to try to reduce the number of variables in your issue, since the CometD demos show that multiple tabs works perfectly fine. You never show your own code, when you are asked for logs you say there is none, so it's very difficult to help you.

Comment: @sbordet : I have edited the main post and added the code. This code which is from the examples is called whenever a new tab or window is loaded. Also, as you can see from the pastebin logs, the first line itself indicates that Cometd detects a duplicate call to /meta/handshake and is calling disconnect. If there is a specific way to call cometd in a new tab, then that's what I am looking for. Secondly, firebug is showing no logs but a counter, where it simply tries to reconnect. I asked it to firebug users, and they said the same.

Comment: @sbordet : ANy ideas? I am simply looking for configuration where cometd would work in multiple tabs, currently it's not. We have not changed any JS side code, it's from sample codes.